# Form field file input doesn't open file browser on Android. Only camera available

Tags: android, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webview

I built a simple web app that allows users to upload a picture. It is just a basic Ruby on Rails app, so frontend is HTML5 and some jQuery.

It all works very well, but on Android only the Camera is available when the user clicks on the file input field. How do I get the file picker to show up?

```
<form class="new_person" id="new_person" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/people" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />

  <input accept="image/*" capture="true" type="file" name="person[picture]" id="person_picture" />

</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct input tag should be

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Try it out on your phone at https://jsfiddle.net/dipish/WWqR5/
When i click on Choose File my Galaxy S4 suggests to either open the camera or the file browser